# How to declare the length/size of an array in php, so users can input any size

Tags: php

In C programming we declare:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define BASE 10 /* constant */

int main{

int freq[BASE]; /* the size of array freq is 10, it can store 10 elements */

}
```

How Do I Convert this in PHP?

Comment: ´$freq = [];´ is an array that can store any amount of items & items can be any type

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: If you absolutely require an array with a fixed size, this exists: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php I've never used it though

Comment: PHP doesn't have a concept of arrays. It has ordered maps which it calls arrays. They have no finite size.

Comment: I understand but think about this if we could declare the size say in this format $a=[12], but this means the index 0 of the array $a has a value 12 in it. But in c if we declare like $a=[12], it means it has the array $a can store 12 elements. They should avail this in php if possible, because i jumped from C to php. Having  confusing time when practising. The SPfixed array concept is good, i assume its new

Comment: PHP is a dynamic language. Imposing strict size restrictions does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you do not have to declare an array size. Just set up the array:

```
$freq = array();
```

Then add to the array as you like:

```
$freq[] = 'foo';
```

To create an array with a defined size you have to add the number of elements to the array that you desire when creating. You could do this with [`array_fill()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php), for example:

```
$freg = array_fill(0, 9, $some_data);
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you define/declare an array by just

```php
$oldSchool = array();
$newSchool = []; // use this one!
```

You can add new elements to it by simply using `[]` next to the array as:

```
$array[] = 'new element';
count($array); // returns the lenght of the array
```

You can easily iterate an array using a foreach loop:

```php
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  echo sprintf('key: %s, value: %s',$key, $value) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

There are plenty of in-build php functions to play with arrays
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: My pleasure. I wrote an article about the new features that brings PHP7.+ https://medium.com/chemaclass/modern-php-know-the-best-php-features-til-php-7-4-e3b2bf5916b2 Check it out :)

Comment: I will definitely have a look, once again tnx, buddy. I am new to this community, really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't have a concept of arrays. It has ordered maps which it calls arrays. They have no finite size. You can't have a fixed size array unless you use the [SplFixedArray class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php)

To create PHP's "array" you can use the following syntax.

```
$myArray = [];
```

To add elements you use keys. This will map one value to another.

```
$myArray['myKey'] = 'My string';
```

You can also use numerical keys or append a new value to the map.

```
$myArray[42] = 'My string of 42';
$myArray[] = 'Appended value'; // the key will be generated by PHP and will be the next available numerical value
```